# Erlang/Mnesia: restricted access to the tables, roles for user access

Tags: erlang, mnesia

The matter is: 
I have a DB on the server that have some users I neeed to make difference in role for each users - one might to write and read, second might only read, last one might nothing.

Question is: 
Is there any in-box solution for it, or should I make my own? In case of my own - which way is right for it? Currently I have no any imagination how could I restrict the access to db through erlang shell.

Answer (score 0):

Probably nothing. Access the erlang shell you get full access to the virtual machine erlang. I know of only one way to limit - it .erlang.cookie file with a password, if you have access to the remote node.
I would be glad if someone correct me if I'm wrong.